# пытаюсь подключить redux но reducer возвращает state undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

Создал папку store в ней создал файлы actionNews, newsReducer, rootReducer, constants.
Подключил "redux": "^4.0.1", "react-redux": "^6.0.1".
в файле newsReducer инициализировал дефолтный state

```js
const defaultState = {
    newCity: {
        name: 'город',
        center: 'центр города',
        points: [1,3],
      }  
};
```

добавил конструкцию свитч кэйс и по дефолту он возвращает дефолтный state.Далее экспортировал редюсер и импортировал в rootReducer.

в файле rootReducer создал combineReducer

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import newsReducer from './newsReducer';
const rootReducer = combineReducers( { newsReducer } );
export default rootReducer;
```

проблема в получении state в файле rootReducer. дефолтное значение не приходит и store созданный в index.js получает значение undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нам бы код всего редюсера. Но пока на вскидку кажется, что должно быть:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import newsReducer from './newsReducer';
const rootReducer = combineReducers( { news: newsReducer } );
export default rootReducer;
```

И дальше в компонентах из стора тащите news.

Answer (score 0):

разобрался. добавил контейнер в него импортировал нужный компонент далее прокинул пропсы с помощью мап диспатч и все заработало ) Store подключился и заработал как надо) Спасибо!